# Changing Google Play Namespace or Signature

Tags: namespaces, key, google-play, signing

Recently we've uploaded/published a baked in application (around 1 million installs) to the google play market.

We uploaded our test beta APK with our test signing + namespace. Now we're stuck since the test-key + namespace are tied together.

Does anyone know of a way to to break the key + namespace? Its extremely important to switch the namespace from out beta-key to our production signing key. -Otherwise 1 million people cannot update.

This APK is pre-installed on the OS with an old version.

Comment: I believe it is impossible to do what you are asking. Why can't you just update with the test key?

Comment: The current users are on the prod key, they will get invalid certs if they try to install from prod to our test-key. We tried to multi sign but google.play wouldn't accept the application upload.

Comment: You can unpublish applications. Perhaps you could unpublish it and then republish it with the same package but different cert. I had a problem with lost certificate but I never tried this.

Comment: We tried that earlier, we've unpublished the main APK that was uploaded about a month ago in testing. When we attempt to upload a new APK with the same namespace is complains for the application to retain the same cert as before.
If we try to upload a new package with the same namespace it complains that we already have that name space taken.

Comment: Well, what you guys are trying to do is impossible by design, for obvious security reasons. Your best bet would probably be to email Google and see if they are willing to work with you.